# how to customize the size of hover in navigation bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am learning bootstrap
I am trying to create a navbar in which it will be shrink when we scroll down and also want to make the hover on links of full size for which i tried so much but i was unable to make it. please help me out to make this navigation bar with full height hover on link. following is the code i have wrote:

HTML Code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="fullheader">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

css code

```
.navbar{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  background-color:#FFf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  /* animation magic */
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out ;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  }

.navbar-default{
background-color:#fff !important;}

.shrink{
  padding: 10px 0;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand,.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover{
    color: #646464;
    margin-left: 80px !important;
}

.shrink .navbar-brand{
    font-size: 20px;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a{
    background-color: #00CCFF!important;
    display:block;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: #FF0000 !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

js code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('body').scrollspy({target: ".navbar", offset: 50});   
      $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function(event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
          event.preventDefault();
          var hash = this.hash;
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 800, function(){
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        }  
      });
    });

$(window).scroll(function(){
            $scrol=$(document).scrollTop();
            //console.log($scrol);
            if($scrol > 100){
              $(".navbar").addClass("shrink");
            }
            else
            {
                $(".navbar").removeClass("shrink");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this? [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/YorkFord/pen/QadoQq)

```
.navbar{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#FFf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  /* animation magic */
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out ;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  }

.navbar-default{
background-color:#fff !important;
min-height: auto;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 40px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out ;
}

.shrink.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a,
.shrink.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 40px;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
  padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  min-height: auto;
height: auto;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand,.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover{
    color: #646464;
    margin-left: 80px !important;
}

.shrink .navbar-brand{
    font-size: 20px;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a{
    background-color: #00CCFF!important;
    display:block;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: #FF0000 !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think @Nikola Kostov's answer got the shrink on scroll right. Is this what you wanted for on hover full size, something like this?

```
  body {height: 2000px;}
.navbar{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#FFf;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  /* animation magic */
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out ;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  }

.navbar-default{
background-color:#fff !important;
min-height: auto;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 40px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out ;
}

.shrink.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a,
.shrink.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 40px;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
  padding: 40px 0;
    font-size: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  min-height: auto;
height: auto;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand,.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover{
    color: #646464;
    margin-left: 80px !important;
}

.shrink .navbar-brand{
    font-size: 20px;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a{
    background-color: #00CCFF!important;
    font-size: 30px;
    display:block;
}



.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: #FF0000 !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```